# How to use functions and their values as parameters?

Tags: javascript

I want an object to call a function defined in another object or JSON (as a string or reference), with a variable number of values also defined there.

Here's a pseudo-code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// function name and variable-length values definition
const definition = {
  functionName: "function1",
  values: [ 1, "foo", 3.14 ]
}

// objectA calling the function with the values
// objectA.definedFunction(definedValues);
// objectA.[functionName]([val1], [val2], ..., [valN]);
objectA.function1(1, "foo", 3.14);
```

Note: `objectA` may/should? reference the definition in a member variable.

How can that be achieved?

And is it possible to expand that so that `function1` is a member function of another object that is also defined in `definition`?

Comment: everything is possible, but I didn't get your question? what is `objectA.function1(1, "foo", 3.14);` where is `objectA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mechanisms you need.

First the square bracket notation to access object properties:

```
objectA[definition.functionName]; // this will return the function you want
// This is the same as objectA.function1
```

Second you want to pass an array as parameter list. For that you can use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which expects the argument list in the form of an array:

```
objectA[definition.functionName].apply(objectA, definition.values);
// This is the same as objectA.function1(1, "foo", 3.14);
```

Answer (score 0):

string to function: [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
const fx1 = Function(definition.functionString)
const fx2 = objectA[definition.functionName]
```

there has serval way to call fx, depend on how fx handle parameter

```js
fx.apply(null, definition.values)
fx(...definition.values)
fx(definition.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object (i.e. dictionary) of functions and their arguments' values, you can get the function simply by accessing its matching value in the dictionary.
Then, in order to use its arguments, you can use the spread operator:

```js
const dictionary = {
  function1: { // For example
    definition: (a, b, c) => `{ a: ${a}, b: ${b}, c: ${c} }`,
    values: [1, "foo", 3.14],
  },
};

function callFunctionByName(name) {
  const currFunction = dictionary[name];
  const { definition, values } = currFunction;
  return definition(...values);
}


console.log(callFunctionByName('function1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let objA = {
   function1: function(a, b, c) {
     console.log(a)
     console.log(b);
     console.log(c);
  }
}
const definition = {
  functionName: "function1",
  values: [ 1, "foo", 3.14 ]
}

objA[definition.functionName].apply(null, definition.values);
```

//Second approach if it function1 is not a key of objA

```
function function1(first, sec, third) {
  
    console.log(first);
    console.log(sec);
    console.log(third);
  
}
const definition = {
  functionName: "function1",
  values: [ 1, "foo", 3.14 ]
}
eval(`${definition.functionName}(${definition.values[0]}, "${definition.values[1]}", ${definition.values[2]})`);
```